# get number of the latest version for pages using powershell script in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, 2010, powershell

I am trying to get the latest version's number

```
foreach($item in $listItems){
$fieldValues = @{
          "Title" = $item["Title"]
          "Created" = $item["Created"]
          "Modified" = $item["Author"]
  "Version"= $item.["_UIVersionString"] // internal name of version

      }
```

Here for all the pages i am getting the version number as `512`

I also tried

```
$item.Versions.Count;
```

It is bringing total number of all the versions(including the minor versions)
i.e if version number 50 has 8 minor versions  (50.8) its counting that as seperate version as well

Is there any other way to get the number of the latest version for items?

Answer (score 2):

```
_UIVersionString “1” = version “0.1”
_UIVersionString “2” = version “0.2”
_UIVersionString “3” = version “0.3”
_UIVersionString “512” = version “1.0”
_UIVersionString “1024” = version “2.0”
_UIVersionString “1025” = version “2.1”
```

Example : If page version is 5.4 Then it will show 2564

```
5 * 512 + 4 = 2564
```

We call this a "base-512" counting system in typical mathematics terms

Answer (score 0):

I think `$item["ows__UIVersionString"]` should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Brian
Its not returning any value though

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

when i was using `"Version"= $item.["_UIVersionString"]` i got base-512 versions as Vaibhav has pointed in his answer

But i am getting the correct version like 23.1 etc when i use `"Version"= item["_UIVersionString"]` **(dot removed)**